# Difference between "rien que ..." and "ne ... que"

Tags: expressions

Both "rien que ..." and "ne ... que" translates into "just/only". But I can’t help feeling that their usages are somewhat different.

I’ve just come up with the example sentences below for the sake of contrasting these two similar-looking phrases. Am I interpreting the difference correctly? Do those sentences make sense?

---

> S'ils m'avaient laissé **rien qu**'une minute de plus, j'aurais pu finir toutes les tâches. (Mais malheureusement, je n'y suis pas arrivée parce qu'en fait je n'ai eu presque aucun temps.)

If (only) they had given me just one more minute, I could’ve completed all the tasks.

---

> S'ils **ne** m'avaient laissé **qu**'une minute de plus, je n'aurais pas pu finir toutes les tâches. (Mais heureusement que j'y suis arrivée parce qu'en fait ils m'ont laissé dix minutes de plus.)

If they hadn’t given me more than a minute, I couldn’t have completed all of the tasks.

Comment: « S'ils ne m'avaient laissé qu'une minute de plus » could be written : « S'ils ne m'avaient laissé rien qu'une minute de plus ». « Rien » here insists on the fact just only one minute would has been sufficient… Compare to "if they had given me one minute more" and "if they had given me just one minute more"…

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour !
Dans votre contexte, on ne peut pas dire de manière correcte "rien que", mais "ne ... rien que". "S'ils ne m'avaient laissé rien qu'une minute de plus,...".
En revanche rien que peut s'utiliser dans "Rien que cela aurait pu suffire " --> "Just this would have sufficed"

En espérant vous avoir aidée, désolé pour ma traduction approximative.

Comment: Pourquoi ? Qu'est-ce que tu as contre « s'ils m'avaient laissé rien qu'une minute de plus » ?

Comment: @Gilles - "s'ils m'avaient laissé rien qu'une minute de plus" est vulgaire. La forme correcte est "s'ils **ne** m'avaient laissé rien qu'une minute de plus".

Answer (score 0):

I feel the two sentences say about the same thing, the first one maybe conveying more insistence on "just a little minute", but the first one feels "vulgar" to me, i.e. grammatically broken, because it lacks that *ne* to make the negation of the verb complete. No doubt you will hear it in the streets. But I hope it's yet not taught in schools.